# Start EC2 windows instance before authentication

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, rdp

When i start my EC2 windows instance using boto python and custom ami, it does not boot up until i login into it using remote desktop and enter my user credentials.

Is there a workaround to avoid this, i just want the to boot up my computer without entering credentials.

Comment: It seems as though there's a significant amount of information missing here. If you're logging into Windows in EC2, it has booted or the network stack wouldn't be up and you couldn't connect to it. What exactly doesn't happen without your credentials? User scripts don't run?

Comment: yes, i have some scripts on startup that don't run. I have to login using RDP then only the desktop is shown and my scripts run.

Comment: What mechanism are you using to run the scripts?  Login script, scheduled tasks?

Comment: I just place them into the windows startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

Things in the startup folder in the start menu only run when the user logs in (and I believe this feature is deprecated too).  They do not run at boot.

If you want them to run at boot, and not at login, create a scheduled task for them or write a windows service that invokes them.

Better still, you could also use linux, which has much better support for this type of thing; on linux you could just add your scripts to the init scripts.

Comment: I am using a windows software, that i have to use. And writing a windows service just to start a program seems too much work. If i disable password for singin inside windows, then it seems to work fine and the system boots up. To disable user authentication: http://tinyurl.com/oltywk5.\

Comment: You need to fix your terminology.  What you are talking about is not part of the boot process.